# Error gradle en android studio

Tags: android, gradle

¿Alguien sabe como reparar este error?

Android studio no se deja crear apk en modo release , ni tampoco crear apk firmada, me dice que le falta este archivo.

Estas son las versiones con las que trabajo:

*- gradle version 4.4

 - android plugin version 3.1.3.

 - windows 10*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar el `gradle` de tu proyecto?, parece que no estás incluyendo el repositorio Maven de Google.

Comment: Haz lo que dice @A.Cedano  creo tambien que ese es tu error de todas formas pon el gradle para estar mas seguros

Comment: exacto , el maven era lo que me faltaba